Is there a way to bypass iptables/ip6tables rules for localhost traffic?
I have a firewall mechanism based on iptables/ip6tables that allows its users to block or accept traffic from hosts, by adding rules at the top of iptables/ip6tables.
I would like all traffic generated by localhost to be allowed no matter the state of iptables/ip6tables.
Is there a way to do that?

Yes, there is a way to do this.

@paladin Can you share it?

There are many ways to do this, however this is all predicated on the OMGWTF of allowing users to edit the firewall config directly. Without knowing a LOT more about the context of this, safeguards and recovery mechanisms it would be unwise to suggest a solution.

One way would be to restrict users to only use the --append (-A) option for appending new rules, and not allow users to use the --insert (-I) option, for inserting new rules to the top of rules chain. When doing so, you use --insert option only for superuser access to firewall rules and create rules for allowing traffic on localhost. You need to make sure that users have no sudo/root access and that users can only edit a restricted part of iptables configuration, which another superuser program/script then assembles with your superuser-iptables configuration and applies it.

No, iptables controls the flow. You cannot possibly always allow localhost no matter the state of iptables. First set a rule
iptables -I INPUT -i lo0 -j ACCEPT

Then don’t allow users to override or add rules on top before this rule. I would suggest not allowing users to fiddle with iptables directly at all, and instead give them a script which they can invoke with predefined functions/parameters that does specific allowed tasks for them.
If you allow users to modify iptables, one could add a rule on top like the one I posted with -j DROP and that’s that. That’s what iptables is for. There is no mechanism to “circumvent iptables for a specific set of parameters”, it’s the job of iptables to handle this.

Yeah, there are ways to bypass iptables/ip6tables rules for localhost traffic.
You can configure the rules to allow all traffic to and from the loopback interface (lo).
For IPv4, allow all traffic on the loopback interface:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

Make sure that localhost traffic is allowed:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT

For IPv6, allow all traffic on the loopback interface:
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

Make sure that  localhost traffic is allowed:
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::1 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d ::1 -j ACCEPT

Save the rules
Debian/Ubuntu:
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"
sudo sh -c "ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6"

Redhat:
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables"
sudo sh -c "ip6tables-save > /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables"

Good luck!

This is tricky and you can easily get hacked due to misconfigurations. It'd be easier to answer if you say more about the system you're using, like the distro and version.
